# add third-party js library to Create React App

Tags: reactjs, import, create-react-app, react-component

I am using chartIQ library in my Create React App. I added it just by using script tag in my index.html file  `<script src="chartiq/js/chartiq.js"></script>` and it works that way, but it does not feel right. Because I need this library only for one component and it would be better to import somehow this library only to this component. Is there any way to do this correcly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it in the following way:

```
function loadScript(url, callback){

    let script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    if (script.readyState){  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        script.onload = function(){
            callback();
        };
    }

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

and then use this function on `componentDidMount()` to load the external script.