# Load amazon script in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, script-tag

I have below script in my react component which works when I refresh the component. But when I navigate between the routes it doesn't work.

```
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react'
import React from 'react'

@inject('store')
@observer
export default class Ads extends React.Component<{}> {
  public componentDidMount() {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.id = 'amzn_assoc_ad_div_adunit0_0'
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.type = 'text/javascript'
    script.src = `//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US`
    const s = document.createElement('script')
    s.type = 'text/javascript'
    const code = `amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0"; 
    amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "teamhansel-20";
    amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
    amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
    amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
    amzn_assoc_region = "US";
    amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "Search Amazon For Cash Back";
    amzn_assoc_default_category = "All";
    amzn_assoc_linkid = "";
    amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
    amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "top";
    amzn_assoc_title = "Shop Related Products"`  
    s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code))
    const dom = document.getElementById('amazon-search-container')
    if(dom) {
      dom.appendChild(s)
      dom.appendChild(script)
    }
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div key={Math.random()}>
        <div className="mt-3 item__wrapper" id="amazon-ads-container"> 
          <div id="amazon-search-container">&nbsp;</div>
          <div id="amzn_assoc_ad_div_adunit0_0">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You can simply setup a react project and try this... please!!!

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you show your Route Setup. Preferably the manner in which Ads component is rendered

Comment: Here you can [check](https://codesandbox.io/s/k27193zoy3) `routes.js`. But I don't think there is any issue with that.

Comment: Can you make sure that the Ads ccomponent is getting remounted on Route change and not re-rendered?

Comment: Yes I am sure. You can simply make a small react setup and can check it. It will work on refresh but not on navigation between routes.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Here is the full fiddle https://codesandbox.io/s/yl90q4r31